# About Transistor Amplification (Voltage amplification in CB mode)

Tags: voltage

[image: I tried to find the error myself, but, here I seem to find two different expressions for the same Vo! Vo=IcRL is dependent on RL only whereas by internal resistance consideration, I found another expression for Vo which is independent of RL]https://youtu.be/Qwd-5H24tRo

Based on that video, I learned that in CB mode Transistors amplify the i/p voltage, based on the fact that the BC junction is reverse biased and so that the o/p dynamic resistance is higher than the i/p one. So, as the I stays almost the same, o/p V is greater than i/p V.

Now, I am thinking, as Vo = IcRL and it doesn't depend on the o/p dynamic resistance of the reverse BC junction, then what if I choose RL less than Ri(i.e i/p dynamic forward bias resistance of EB junction), how can then the transistor amplify even though being in active region (I've biased the Transistor to be working in the active region, just changed the value of RL)?

Update: I tried to find the error myself, but, here I seem to find two different expressions for the same Vo! Vo=IcRL is dependent on RL only whereas by internal resistance consideration, I found another expression for Vo which is independent of RL! (About the image)

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The CB configuration is basically a **current buffer** configuration. Its a current amplifier with gain = 1. So ic / ie = 1. When you try to look at **voltage gain** with the CB stage the input impedance and output impedance become relevant. Then basically the voltage gain is the ratio between the two: gain = Rout/Rin. To sum up: the CB stage is not intended as a voltage amplifier so don't try to treat it like that.